# how to change UI element in a new thread task.onDone()?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, task

How can I make this happend?

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FacebookConnectTask task = 
                new FacebookConnectTask("facebookId", "token", "email", facebookGender,0, 0);
        task.setOnPreExecuteListener(this);
        task.setOnDoneListener(this);
        task.execute();
    }
});
t.start();

public void onPreExecute() { 
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void onDone() { 
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Since I am opening a new thread, I can not change a UI element in it, so, How can I manage to do something to the UI, when the task starts and when it's finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the work in an `AyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` executes everything in `doInBackground()` inside of another thread, which does not have access to the GUI where your views are.

`preExecute()` and `postExecute()` offer you access to GUI before and after the heavy lifting occurs in this new thread, you can even pass the result of the long operation to `postExecute()` to then show any results of processing.

More here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Example here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: before i saw your answer i tried runOnUiThread(new Runnable... and it worked.
Do you think its an exaptable solution? it looks a bit of a msss to me...

Comment: It's convenient, really. The AsyncTask framework deals with managing the Thread pool and provides a simple, understandable interface. -- the UI activity can go on in `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()`, and that all of the "heavy lifting" is done in `doInBackground()` where you are not allowed to touch the UI. Why not go with that than to create and try to manage your own threads

Answer (score 1):

inside your activity

```
private Handler myHandler=new Handler();
```

next in your on done callback

```
public void onDone() { 
myHandler.post(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run() {
      progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
   }
})
}
```

But as already was said. AsyncTask is more siutable for it